# Footer and Watermark added by iTextSharp not appearing in Edge but OK in Chrome

Tags: pdf, itext, azure-blob-storage, microsoft-edge, pdfstamper

I create pdfs using iTextSharp and add a footnote and watermark to these using a PdfStamper. This has been working fine. Recently the footers and watermarks have not been appearing when the pdfs are viewed in MS Edge. However, if I view the same pdf in Chrome the footers and watermarks appear correctly.

I store the pdfs in blob storage in Azure.

I have recently changed iTextSharp version from V4.1.2.0 to V5.5.13.

The code for adding watermarks and footers is as follows:

```
    Dim byteArray As Byte()
    Using stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
        reportBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(stream)
        reader = New PdfReader(CType(stream.ToArray(), Byte()))
        If reader IsNot Nothing Then
            Using stamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(reader, stream)
                Dim PageCount As Integer = reader.NumberOfPages
                If bReportInvalid Then
                    For i As Integer = 1 To PageCount
                        StampWaterMark(stamper, i, "INVALID", fontReport60, 35, New text.BaseColor(70, 70, 255), reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
                    Next
                ElseIf Not UserRoles.Contains(WaspWAVB.con.csUserRoleCertificateSignOff) Then
                    For i As Integer = 1 To PageCount
                        StampWaterMark(stamper, i, "DRAFT", fontReport60, 35, New text.BaseColor(70, 70, 255), reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
                    Next
                End If
                If bAddFooter Then
                    Dim sRepUCN As String = "UCN"
                    Dim sCopyright As String = "Copyright"
                    Dim yPos As Integer = 12
                    Dim xLeftPos As Integer = 36
                    Dim xMidPos As Single = 297.5
                    Dim xRightPos As Integer = 559
                    For i As Integer = 3 To PageCount - iAppendixCount
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT, New text.Phrase(sRepUCN, fontMedium), xLeftPos, yPos, 0)
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, New text.Phrase(sCopyright, fontMedium), xMidPos, yPos, 0)
                        Dim rttnPg As Integer = reader.GetPageRotation(i)
                        If rttnPg <> 0 Then
                            xRightPos = 806
                        End If
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, New text.Phrase(String.Format(WaspWAVB.con.csPageXofY, i - 2, PageCount - 2 - iAppendixCount), fontMedium), xRightPos, yPos, 0)
                    Next
                End If
            End Using
            byteArray = stream.ToArray()
        End If
    End Using
    reportBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    reportBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

    Public Shared Sub StampWaterMark(ByRef stamper As PdfStamper,
                                   ByVal i As Integer,
                                   ByVal watermark As String,
                                   ByVal font As text.Font,
                                   ByVal angle As Single,
                                   ByVal color As text.BaseColor,
                                   ByVal realPageSize As text.Rectangle,
                                   Optional ByVal rect As text.Rectangle = Nothing)

        Dim gstate = New PdfGState()
        gstate.FillOpacity = 0.1F
        gstate.StrokeOpacity = 0.3F
        stamper.GetOverContent(i).SaveState()
        stamper.GetOverContent(i).SetGState(gstate)
        stamper.GetOverContent(i).SetColorFill(color)
        stamper.GetOverContent(i).BeginText()
        Dim ps = If(rect, realPageSize)
        Dim x = (ps.Right + ps.Left) / 2
        Dim y = (ps.Bottom + ps.Top) / 2
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, New text.Phrase(watermark, font), x, y, angle)

    End Sub
```

I have tried re-arranging the order in which the footer and watermark are applied and commenting out either the addition of watermark or footer. None of this helps.

I use the code to add a footer elsewhere in the code and this works. Where it works, the footer is applied to an individual page. Where it doesn't work I have just collected together pages stored in separate blobs and amalgamated them into one memorystream. The footer and watermark are applied to this.

What is mystifying is that the pdf works fine in Chrome but not in Edge. This works either way round - i.e. if I create it in Chrome and view it in Edge, the footers disappear and if I create it in Edge and view it in Chrome, the footers appear.

Has anyone else seen this problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with Edge. Are you sure that Edge supports transparency? I have the impression it doesn't. Please don't blame iText for problems in Edge!

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks. I love iTextSharp and am thankful that you always respond to problems. I don't know what the problem is or where to point the finger! The footers and watermarks are working fine on my current live site in all browsers including Edge. I have made substantial changes between this version and my latest version. One is to upgrade from iText V4.1.2.0 to iText V5.5.13. Another is that I now store sections of my report in Azure blobs and pull these out into a memory stream to create the final report. Previously I stored the sections in text files and pulled them into a FileStream

Comment: Please note that iText 5.5.13 is a *maintenance* release of a version that is no longer supported. Maintenance releases are made for paying users who can't migrate to the new iText version (e.g. because it requires too much work). We renamed **iTextSharp** to **iText for .NET**, and we released [iText 7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/) about two years ago.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I added iTextSharp through the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio. I didn't realise that it had changed it's name to iText so that is the most recent version that comes up on a search for iTextSharp. So, which version should I be using and will I have to make code changes if I change version? I work on my own so find it hard to get up to date info.

Comment: iText 7 is a complete rewrite of iText 5. The design we used for iText 5 was outdated, so we had to change the API. This means that it will be harder to migrate from 5 to 7 than it was to migrate from 4 to 5.

Comment: @Rachel That all being said, can you share an example PDF with which that happens? *"Recently the footers and watermarks have not been appearing"* sounds like an issue related to your PDF as they are coming now.